# extract values from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The first and the second data frames are as below:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'0': [2154,799,1023,4724], '1': [27, 2981, 952,797],'2':[4905,569,4767,569]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and

```
d={'PART_NO': ['J661-03982','661-08913', '922-8972','661-00352','661-06291',''], 'PART_NO_ENCODED': [2154,799,1023,27,569]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to get the corresponding part_no for each row in df1 so the resulting data frame should look like this:

```
d={'PART_NO': ['J661-03982','661-00352',''], 'PART_NO_ENCODED': [2154,27,4905]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This I can achieve like this:

```
df2.set_index('PART_NO_ENCODED').reindex(df1.iloc[0,:]).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'PART_NO_ENCODED'})
```

But instead of passing `reindex(df1.iloc[0,:])` one value that's 0,1 at a Time I want to get for all the rows in df1 the corresponding part_no. Please help?

Comment: The definition of `d` for `df2` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second dataframe as a dictionary of replacements:

```
df3 = df1.replace(df2.set_index('PART_NO_ENCODED').to_dict()['PART_NO'])
```

The values that are not in `df2`, will not be replaced. They have to be identified and discarded:

```
df3 = df3[df1.isin(df2['PART_NO_ENCODED'].tolist())]
#            0          1          2
#0  J661-03982  661-00352        NaN
#1   661-08913        NaN  661-06291
#2    922-8972        NaN        NaN
#3         NaN        NaN  661-06291
```

You can later replace the missing values with `''` or any other value of your choice with `fillna`.